# Zero Fill Right Shift in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm having a little tinker with Haskell (and thouroughly enjoying myself) and I now want to do a [zero-fill right shift](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftRightZeroFill.htm).

I trotted on over to hackage and found [Data.Bits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Bits.html), whipped up [ghci](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi) and here's what I typed (well, I didn't type the -3 of course):

```
:m Data.Bits   
shiftR (-9) 2
-3
```

Fantatstic, a regular right shift, just what I expected.

OK, now I'll actually read the docs.  OK, I see `unsafeShiftR`, but that's not quite what I want.

So, what have I missed?  Is there a zero-fill right shift function available to me in Haskell somewhere (i.e. one that returns 1073741821 when -9 is shifted right by 2)?

Comment: Is `shiftR` not what you need?  I would recommend using fixed length types though, like `Data.Word.Word8`: `shiftR (1 :: Word8) 1 === 0`, `rotateR (1 :: Word8) 1 === 128`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Data.Bits` takes signed types into account. However, since any zero fill right shift with non-zero shift will result in a unsigned type, you can simply transform your input to a word of the correct size:

```
-- :m Data.Word
-- shiftR ((fromIntegral x) :: Word32) 2
shiftR (-9 :: Word32) 2
1073741821
```